# Checking if elements of a tweets array contain one of the elements of positive words array and count

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We are building sentiment analysis application and we converted our tweets dataframe to an array. We created another array consisting of positive words. But we cannot count the number of tweets containing one of those positive words. We tried these and we get 1 as result. It must be more than 1. Apparently it did not count:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
var tweetDF = sqlContext.read.json("hdfs:///sandbox/tutorial-files/770/tweets_staging/*")
tweetDF.show()
var messages = tweetDF.select("msg").collect.map(_.toSeq) 
println("Total messages: " + messages.size)
val positive = Source.fromFile("/home/teslavm/positive.txt").getLines.toArray
var happyCount=0
for (e <- 0 until messages.size) {
    for (f <- 0 until positive.size) {
        if (messages(e).contains(positive(f))){
        happyCount=happyCount+1
    }
    }
}
print("\nNumber of happy messages: " +happyCount)
```

[image]

Comment: Which error are you getting? BTW, it is not recommended to call `collect` on **Spark**, you lose all the advantages of distributed computing and if the _dataset_ is pretty big you would blow out the memory.

Comment: I editted my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. 
It has the advantage that you do not have to collect the result, as well as being more functional.

```
val messages = tweetDF.select("msg").as[String]

val positiveWords =
  Source
    .fromFile("/home/teslavm/positive.txt")
    .getLines
    .toList
    .map(word => word.toLowerCase)

def hasPositiveWords(message: String): Boolean = {
  val _message = message.toLowerCase
  positiveWords.exists(word => _message.contains(word))
}  

val positiveMessages = messages.filter(hasPositiveWords _)

println(positiveMessages.count())
```

I tested this code locally with:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val tweetDF = List(
  (1, "Yes I am happy"),
  (2, "Sadness is a way of life"),
  (3, "No, no, no, no, yes")
).toDF("id", "msg")

val positiveWords = List("yes", "happy")
```

And it worked.

Comment: gives error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Comment: Can you provide a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how to create the `tweetDF` so I can test the code myself. It could be just the `show` of your actual DF.

Comment: I added to my question

Comment: @büşratabak could you give it another try after the edit and see if it works? If not, could you please check with the simple tests I made? You can replace the `positiveWords` list with the one reading from a file, it should work too.